# SQL How to avoid groupby

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that it results is not correct and I assume it `groupby` issue

> Fiddle

This is my [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f660b77da8c6b1fa993a400f1663dbd)

> Query

```
SELECT  UPPER(reg.Title) as TITLE1, 
        UPPER(cust.[Name]) as CUSTOMER,
        Rmember.DisplayName as  USERNAME, 
        Rmember.Email as USEREmail,
    COUNT(dbo.Request.Id) as REQUESTS
FROM    dbo.Customer as cust INNER JOIN
         dbo.Registry as reg ON cust.Id = reg.CustomerId INNER JOIN
         dbo.RegistryMember as Rmember ON reg.Id = Rmember.RegistryId full JOIN
         dbo.Request ON reg.Id = dbo.Request.RegistryId
WHERE   Rmember.Email like '%PNEVMA%'
group by  reg.Title, cust.[Name], Rmember.DisplayName,Rmember.Email
order by  reg.Title
```

> Result

[image]

> Expected

In reality only `user1` has done 4 requests

[image]

Comment: Please share with us the original table and it's data. Only with that we can help you in the right way. Also share with us your expected results. One more thing, why do you have this column "cust.LegalName" in the group by  and it is not in the select ?

Comment: Here, try to fill/change this out https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f79bc7178e914452fc0c4a5f68a47d5 and use it as a question

Comment: "cust.LegalName" removed and Expected Filled.
How could I share all the data o all these tables?

Comment: it is very simple, I have provided you with a link and for few users it is really not a big problem to fill the data...

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f660b77da8c6b1fa993a400f1663dbd)

Comment: Hi @PanMarkosian great fiddle, I suggest to edit the question and add the fiddle there and change your expected result according to this fiddle...

Comment: I solved it using Left Join answered from [Thorsten Kettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner), thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result shows one registry with 'Title1'. Per registry you can have many users (in table RegistryMember). And per registry you can have many requests (in table Request).

Now you say that you get wrong counts, because only 'User 1' made requests. There is nothing in your query, though, to link a request to a user. So obviously you are missing this in your join. (A full outer join makes no sense in your query by the way). The join should look something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.Request ON reg.Id = Request.RegistryId and Rmember.UserId = Request.UserId
```

or

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.Request ON Rmember.RegistryId = Request.RegistryId
                     AND Rmember.UserId = Request.UserId
```

because a request links to a request member.

You must adapt this to your actual table columns of course. I just saw your db fiddle and became a little confused by RequestedBy_Id linking to a member ID or a registry member ID (which I do not know, nor do I know the difference between the two) and by RequestedBy_Name and RequestedBy_Email which can obviously be different from the real/current (?) name and email of the registry member and maybe even from that of the member. All this looks a bit redundant, but this may be on purpose. You will know, what columns to actually join the tables on.

Comment: I agree with jarlh here, by the way. I, too, would aggregate before joining. The issue is the same then of course; you must aggregate and join not only on a registry, but a registry member.

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN`'s and `GROUP BY` require some extra care.

A simple trick is to do *correlated subquery* instead:

```
SELECT  UPPER(reg.Title) as TITLE1, 
        UPPER(cust.[Name]) as CUSTOMER,
        Rmember.DisplayName as  USERNAME, 
        Rmember.Email as USEREmail,
        (SELECT COUNT(dbo.Request.Id) from dbo.Request
         WHERE reg.Id = dbo.Request.RegistryId) as REQUESTS
FROM    dbo.Customer as cust INNER JOIN
         dbo.Registry as reg ON cust.Id = reg.CustomerId INNER JOIN
         dbo.RegistryMember as Rmember ON reg.Id = Rmember.RegistryId 
WHERE   Rmember.Email like '%PNEVMA%'
order by  reg.Title
```

Perhaps you need `SELECT DISTINCT`, to avoid duplicated rows. (Depends on your data.)

You can also aggregate before you `JOIN`, in a *derived table*:

```
SELECT  UPPER(reg.Title) as TITLE1, 
        UPPER(cust.[Name]) as CUSTOMER,
        Rmember.DisplayName as  USERNAME, 
        Rmember.Email as USEREmail,
        REQUESTS.RequestCount
FROM    dbo.Customer as cust INNER JOIN
        dbo.Registry as reg ON cust.Id = reg.CustomerId INNER JOIN
        dbo.RegistryMember as Rmember ON reg.Id = Rmember.RegistryId LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT dbo.Request.RegistryId, COUNT(dbo.Request.Id) RequestCount
         from dbo.Request
         GROUP BY dbo.Request.RegistryId) as REQUESTS ON reg.Id = REQUESTS.RegistryId
   WHERE   Rmember.Email like '%PNEVMA%'
order by  reg.Title
```

(Changed to `LEFT JOIN` here.)

Comment: Rather than resorting to sub-queries, these types of situations almost always result from bad join conditions or grouping, which per the OP's comments also appear to be the case here.

Comment: Edit your question and show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) I.e. [mcve].